# Sum to determine the largest multiple of 5 under 1,000

Tags: java, math, equation

I am currently trying to get a feature working in a Java application I am making, however I'm uncertain how to implement this in a single line.

I know that I could do something along the lines of (not *exactly*, but roughly):

```
while(i<995){
i=i+5
}
```

However I am eager to implement this all into one line, such as in a single

```
static int highestMult = *the equation*
```

I would not be using this specifically for the highest multiple of 5 in 1,000, however upon my own research I could not find a desired solution for this specific case, therefore this is an example.

The examples I have previously found all, generally, relate to finding only a highest multiple, not putting together the highest multiple, and a limit.

If this is not knowledge from the back of your head, it'd also be a great help just to understand the logic behind how you came up with the solution, it could save me being stuck on similar issues in the future.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `c` is the *under* number (1000 in your case), and `m` the multiple (5 in your case), then

`((c - 1) / m) * m`

is one way. (Note to purists: you don't actually need the outer parentheses but I include them for clarity).

Here I'm exploiting *integer arithmetic* to force the truncation of `((c - 1) / m)` to the flooring integer. Multiplication of this result by `m` means the final value is a multiple of `m`. Make sure that `c` and `m` are integral types or this will not work (unless you cast explicitly which is not as elegant).

This is undefined for `c < 1` and `m < 1`

Comment: +1 This is a faster for calculating :D, It took so long to calculate remainder (so long I mean someting in microseconds :D), but If you want to do it many times, you could maybe see the differecne

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
int number=5;
int limit=999;
int i=limit-(limit%number);
```

where 999 is `limit - 1`

% is reminder

```
(999%5)=4
```

if we remove the reminder from limit, we will got it:

```
 999-4=995
```

we could use `limit=1000`, but result could be 1000 too

reminder is very useful thing for programming :D

defined for `number > 0` and `limit >=0`

Comment: +1 I prefer this in many ways to my approach as it is less exploitative and possibly easier to follow.